# How can I create an instance of a class implementing an interface from a method?

Tags: java

I have the following probem.
I have these Java classes:

```
class A {
    B makeB() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class B implements X {
    // X methods implementations (plus other methods)
}

interface X {
    // methods declarations
}
```

For testing purposes, I need to modify the method `makeB` so that it can create a new instance of every class that implements the X interface.

I tried with generics:

```
class A<T extends X> {
    X makeB() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

but this code isn't correct.
I also tried in the following way:

```
class A {
    X makeB() {
        return X.createInstance();
    }
}

class B implements X {
    @Override
    public static X createInstance() {
        return new B();
    }
    // X methods implementations (plus other methods)
}

interface X {
    static X createInstance() {}
    // other methods declarations
}
```

but Java doesn't support overriding of static methods.
How can I change `makeB` so that it behaves as I want (if there is a way to do so)?
(Neither the title neither the description of my question are very clear, the problem is that I can't find a way to say it better. My apologies.)
Thanks to everyone who will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org) a unit test framework which allow you to mock (override/redefine) method implementations.

Also have a look to the [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) pattern which help to solve issues like this one.

Comment: I think dependency injection is what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Generics might be a better way to go. Your generic's code is syntactically incorrect. Try this:

```
class A<T extends X> {
    T makeB() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: There was an error in my code, now it is "correct". By the way, the IDE says that I can't instantiate the T type, because it is a generic type.